# Can you determine when the "Service Battery" warning came on for a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

I have a Macbook Pro 7,1 that may or may not have been damaged from water the other day. I noticed that the battery indicator now has the 'Service Battery' showing. I'm wondering if it's possible to determine **when** the warning turned on because that will give me an idea as to whether this is a water damage issue or just because it's almost 6 years old.

CoconutBattery says my battery has 972 load cycles and is only operating on 37% capacity.

**Update**: while I still don't have an answer to this question, I bought a new (and expensive) MagSafe charger for this MacBook that did the trick. I was able to easily rip off the tip of the old charger (the bit that connects to the Macbook), so I think it was pretty frayed already. Perhaps that was the problem.

While the battery still says "Service", it does charge up normally now.

Comment: It's probably just from being old, but I'm not sure how to verify this.